# An algorithm that return true if a given string match a given pattern

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Anyone has an idea of how to implement an algorithm finding if string match a specific pattern?( not contains it!) **without the use of regular expression...**

Rules are,the pattern can hold sign like ? or *:
? = one character or number
* = multiple characters or number or non at all

For example:

isMatching("??Ab", "cbAb") return true.
isMatching("*a?Ab", "123cacAbAAb") return false.
isMatching("*a?Ab", "123aaAb") return true.
isMatching("*a?Ab", "007aaabAb") return true.

isMatching("a?D*", "arD1324687e") return true.

Comment: Look at how regex work behind the scenes and build your own implementation.

Comment: one more question: what should `("*?Ab, "cbAb")` return?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: true in my opinion its equal to writing "??Ab" in this case

Comment: well, but judging by your statement "* = **multiple** characters or number or non at all" it should return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some type of recursion would be simple enough:

```
def match(pattern, str):
    return match_(pattern, str)

def match_(pattern, str)
   if len(pattern) == 0 and len(str) == 0:
       return True

   switch pattern[0]:
       case '?':
            match_(pattern[1: ], str[1: ])
       case '*':
            return match_(pattern, str[1: ]) or match_(pattern[1: ], str[1: ]) or match_(pattern[1: ], str)
       default:
            return pattern[0] == str[0] and match_(pattern[1: ], str[1: ])
```

Comment: Can you explain more the `pattern[1: ]` syntax meaning, and why not do so in iterative method?

Comment: Oh, it's just some pseudocode mashed up from Python & C. Here x[1: ] means the substring formed by x's second and onward characters. For efficiency, you could just pass the strings and their indices instead of actually building these substrings) - I was just writing pseudocode. Also, there's no inherent reason to do it in either recursion or iteration - whatever works for you.